How to connect airflow continer with hdfs container
Currently I'm using docker for HDFS and airflow both have share the network but I can't use HDFS commands inside the airflow container I've tried to install apache-airflow-providers-apache-hdfs but I still can't see HDFS in the connect type in the airflow UI here is part of the docker file
version: '3.8'

x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  build: .
  #image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.8.0}
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: LocalExecutor
    AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth,airflow.api.auth.backend.session'
    AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__ENABLE_HEALTH_CHECK: 'true'
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - /workspaces/proj/airflow/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - /workspaces/proj/airflow/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - /workspaces/proj/airflow/config:/opt/airflow/config
    - /workspaces/proj/airflow/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  namenode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: namenode
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9870:9870
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - hadoop_namenode:/hadoop/dfs/name
      - /workspaces/proj/data:/data
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=test
    env_file:
      - ./config
    networks:
      - etl_task

  datanode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: datanode
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - hadoop_datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870"
    env_file:
      - ./config
    networks:
      - etl_task

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
    networks:
      - etl_task

I've tried to install Hadoop inside the airflow container using apt-get install but always ends up with this error E: Unable to locate package hadoop. Note that I'm using GitHub Codespace

Hadoop is not an apt package... Where did you find those instructions? Have you tried a SparkOperator instead?
